# ClassCastException for Remote Bean on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

When trying to cast a Bean i got through InitialContext#lookup() i get a ClassCastException like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: EJB31_Generated__MyTestBean__Intf____Bean__ cannot be cast to ...
```

or

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy338 cannot be cast to de.package.name.beans.YourBeanInterface
```

where MyTestBean is the Bean I'm trying to access.

Both apps run on the same webserver. The MyTestBean implements an Interface that is annotated with @javax.ejb.Remote. I do get an Object from the lookup and I checked via

```
logger.e(Arrays.toString(o.getClass().getInterfaces()));
logger.e(Arrays.toString(o.getClass().getMethods()));
```

that it indeed does implement that very interface and even has the methods. I can even invoke the methods successfully through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I've no Idea what resolved it in the end and was unable to track it down. But here are a couple of things i learned and that might be helpful tracking down this problem:

- You might want to let your "Remote"-Interface extend from Serializable and provide a serialVersionUID. It does not seem to be necessary however.
- When using the maven war plugin, make sure you have not set archiveClasses to true. Or if you did so, make sure your beans.xml is in the right place (src\main\resources\META-INF?)
- be sure to use the *interface* jndi name of the bean. I.e. : ctx.lookup("java:global/youarpp/YourBean!de.package.name.beans.YourBeanInterface"); - not the implementation.
- Make sure to use the correct @javax.inject.Singleton or @javax.ejb.Singleton, see http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html for some more explanations
- You may have to use @LocalBean if you want to inject the implementation (not only the interface) in the app where it is defined
- in general if the behavior seems strange, try to stop/start-domain and clear any folders of the glassfish instance from time to time (applications, generated, osgi-cache)